# How to load tableView from the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I receive data from the server and when they come to me the table is updated, how to make sure that when the data came the table would creep down to the bottom?

```
tableView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
```

don't working

Comment: Have you tried to reload the tableView before you call tableView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

tableView has no method scrollToBottom, I think you should add this method in the extension of UITableView

**Example** :

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        let y = contentSize.height - frame.size.height
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: (y<0) ? 0 : y), animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tableView.scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)`. For example, let's assume you have an array of string that are show in the table view:

```
var items = ["1", "2", "3"]

func scrollToBottom() {
    let indexPathToReach = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPathToReach, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Update table view data source after receiving data.
2. Reload table view (call `reloadData()` method) or insert cells (call `insertRows(at:with:)` method) in main thread.
3. Scroll to bottom (call `scrollToRow(at:at:animated:)` method) in main thread.